# IF statement in stored procedure (total noob)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Background: I have a table that has a list of people, and another table for events that happen. I need the date that an event happened last for a person updated in a column for the database of the people.

So my understanding would be that I need to create and run a stored procedure with SQL Server agent that would do this for me. I have never written a stored procedure though, so this is also practice for me.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Gary Senter
-- Create date: 5/25/2019
-- Description: Returns employee data.
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLocal_Safety_Sync] 
    @LastName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL, 
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @injury_date DATETIME;
    DECLARE @short_name_1 VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @short_name_2 VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @short_name_3 VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @cc_roster_id_emp_1 INT;
    DECLARE @cc_roster_id_emp_2 INT;
    DECLARE @cc_roster_id_emp_3 INT;

    SELECT 
        @short_name_1 = effected_employee_1,
        @short_name_2 =  effected_employee_2, 
        @short_name_3 = effected_employee_3,
        @injury_date = IncidentDate 
    FROM
        HSEBE.dbo.MCA_Data
    WHERE  
        (Classification = 'XX RI' OR Classification = 'YY RI')
    ORDER BY 
        IncidentDate ASC

    IF LEN(@short_name_1) > 0 
    THEN
        SELECT @cc_roster_id_emp_1 = autoid 
        FROM cc_rosters 
        WHERE short_name = @short_name_1

    IF LEN(@short_name_2) > 0 
    THEN
        SELECT @cc_roster_id_emp_2 = autoid 
        FROM cc_rosters 
        WHERE short_name = @short_name_2

    IF LEN(@short_name_3) > 0 
    THEN
        SELECT @cc_roster_id_emp_3 = autoid 
        FROM cc_rosters 
        WHERE short_name = @short_name_3

    IF @cc_roster_id_emp_1 > 0 
    THEN
        UPDATE cc_rosters 
        SET most_recent_injury = @injury_date 
        WHERE autoid = @short_name_1

    IF @cc_roster_id_emp_2 > 0 
    THEN
        UPDATE cc_rosters 
        SET most_recent_injury = @injury_date 
        WHERE autoid = @short_name_2

    IF @cc_roster_id_emp_3 > 0 
    THEN
        UPDATE cc_rosters 
        SET most_recent_injury = @injury_date 
        WHERE autoid = @short_name_3
END
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spLocal_Safety_Sync, Line 28
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spLocal_Safety_Sync, Line 30
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spLocal_Safety_Sync, Line 32
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spLocal_Safety_Sync, Line 35
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spLocal_Safety_Sync, Line 37
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spLocal_Safety_Sync, Line 39
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.

Not sure where to turn from here....

There will not always be an effected_employee_1,2,3, and sometimes the selected value will not be returned from the other database.

Comment: T-SQL's [IF](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql) has no `THEN`.

Comment: That worked! it only updated 1 record though. from my first select statement the result should have returned 17 rows. how to i get it to update them all?

Comment: With out some source data and some example of expected output it might be difficult to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is a bit much and I understand youre still learning, so let me show you how i would handle this. Also, take this with a grain of salt b/c I dont have visibility to the data or a expected output. I *think* this will get your there. Down side though is that it updates for each employee each time. You could alter to check for matches and exclude those easily, but this was more of a teaching moment than anything else.

First of all let me explain what I see the issue to be here:

1. It looks like you have a bad data structure in the MCA_Data table. By that I mean its a "flat" table with multiple Employees in one row for an incident. This is generally a PITA when it comes doing tasks for reviewing data in many to one situations. Normally there would be a table where incident records get logged separately for each person involved with an incident ID and an employeeID. I understand you probably didnt build it, but its worth pointing out for you own information.
2. Fundamentally, this issue would be easier to appproach once you understood how that less than desirable structure affects what youre task is. This is essentially, in my mind, a pivot problem. PIVOT in SQL is essentially switching rows and columns. If we want to find the max Incident date for every employee, we just need to alter the data in the MCA_Data table for easier processing, right? There are may ways to pivot data with code - pick your favorite - most people actually use the function PIVOT, where I tend to teeter between CTE's (common table experessions) and PIVOT. IMO CTE's are easier to read once you understand them. Run this code and see if if returns the correct result.

   ```
      ; WITH CTE AS
      (
           SELECT Employee, AutoID, MAX(IncidentDate) AS MaxIncidentDate
           FROM
               (
                   SELECT 
                       effected_employee_1 AS Employee,
                       cc1.autoID AS AutoID,
                       MAX(IncidentDate) AS IncidentDate 
                   FROM 
                       HSEBE.dbo.MCA_Data mca
                   LEFT JOIN 
                       cc_rosters cc1 ON mac. effected_employee_1 = cc1. short_name
                   WHERE  
                       (Classification = 'XX RI' OR Classification = 'YY RI')
                       AND effected_employee_1 IS NOT NULL
                   GROUP BY 
                       effected_employee_1,
                       cc1.autoID
                   UNION
                   SELECT 
                       effected_employee_2 AS Employee,
                       cc2.AutoID  AS AutoID,
                       MAX(IncidentDate) AS IncidentDate 
                   FROM 
                       HSEBE.dbo.MCA_Data mca
                   LEFT JOIN 
                       cc_rosters cc2 ON mac. effected_employee_2 = cc2. short_name
                   WHERE  
                       (Classification = 'XX RI' OR Classification = 'YY RI')
                       AND effected_employee_2 IS NOT NULL 
                   GROUP BY 
                       effected_employee_2,
                       cc2.autoID                          
                   UNION
                   SELECT 
                       effected_employee_3 AS Employee, 
                       cc3.autoID AS AutoID,
                       MAX(IncidentDate) AS IncidentDate 
                   FROM 
                       HSEBE.dbo.MCA_Data mca
                   LEFT JOIN 
                       cc_rosters cc3 ON mac. effected_employee_3 = cc3. short_name
                   WHERE  
                       (Classification = 'XX RI' OR Classification = 'YY RI')
                       AND effected_employee_3 IS NOT NULL
                   GROUP BY 
                       effected_employee_3,
                       cc3.autoID      
               ) x
           GROUP BY 
               Employee, AutoID,
       )   
   SELECT * FROM CTE
   ```

   3. Now after you have your max incident dates for each employee where the columns are not null, you can simply just update from here. Updating via joins is something that you'll want to get good at. Prevents all those IF's and variables and the various statements. This also helps you do things in a set based fashion. You'll keep hearing this as you continue on your learning path. I suggest understanding it!

      ```
      ; WITH CTE AS
      (
          SELECT Employee, AutoID, MAX(IncidentDate) AS MaxIncidentDate
          FROM
              (
                  SELECT 
                      effected_employee_1 AS Employee,
                      cc1.autoID AS AutoID,
                      MAX(IncidentDate) AS IncidentDate 
                  FROM 
                      HSEBE.dbo.MCA_Data mca
                  LEFT JOIN 
                      cc_rosters cc1 ON mac. effected_employee_1 = cc1. short_name
                  WHERE  
                      (Classification = 'XX RI' OR Classification = 'YY RI')
                      AND effected_employee_1 IS NOT NULL
                  GROUP BY 
                      effected_employee_1,
                      cc1.autoID
                  UNION
                  SELECT 
                      effected_employee_2 AS Employee,
                      cc2.AutoID  AS AutoID,
                      MAX(IncidentDate) AS IncidentDate 
                  FROM 
                      HSEBE.dbo.MCA_Data mca
                  LEFT JOIN 
                      cc_rosters cc2 ON mac. effected_employee_2 = cc2. short_name
                  WHERE  
                      (Classification = 'XX RI' OR Classification = 'YY RI')
                      AND effected_employee_2 IS NOT NULL 
                  GROUP BY 
                      effected_employee_2,
                      cc2.autoID                          
                  UNION
                  SELECT 
                      effected_employee_3 AS Employee, 
                      cc3.autoID AS AutoID,
                      MAX(IncidentDate) AS IncidentDate 
                  FROM 
                      HSEBE.dbo.MCA_Data mca
                  LEFT JOIN 
                      cc_rosters cc3 ON mac. effected_employee_3 = cc3. short_name
                  WHERE  
                      (Classification = 'XX RI' OR Classification = 'YY RI')
                      AND effected_employee_3 IS NOT NULL
                  GROUP BY 
                      effected_employee_3,
                      cc3.autoID      
              ) x
          GROUP BY 
              Employee, AutoID,
      )
      UPDATE r SET r.most_recent_injury = cte.MaxIncidentDate
      FROM cc_rosters r
      INNER JOIN CTE ON r.AutoID = CTE.AutoID AND r.short_name =cte.Employee;
      ```
   4. In procedures where you have multiple commands, get used to using the ';' character to terminate each line. Its a good practice to be in.

Comment: I was going to say show me what youre doing but it seems like you got it figured out. How about hooking me up with a answer check mark and an upvote?